# GTA V - how long does a full set of supplies last?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA I have a cocaine lockup with no upgrades if I bought supplies and they were full how long would it take for the supplies to run out and need resupplying

Answer (score 1):

When staff is assigned solely to production the supplies are used at these rates:

No upgrades - 1 unit every 60 seconds.

Partially Upgraded - 1 unit every ~72 seconds.

Fully Upgraded - 1 unit every 84 seconds.

No upgrades the bar will deplete every 100 minutes. ( 1hr 40minutes)

Fully upgraded the bar will deplete every 140 minutes. (2hr 20 minutes)

Full Guide can be found [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/6hhct4/gunrunning_business_guide_and_notes/)

Comment: Are these numbers the same for MC businesses or are they different?

Comment: They should be- if you notice anything odd post it here